# How to use authentication in an HTTP Proxy?

Tags: http-proxy

I am currently researching FreeProxy 4.10.

I just noticed that one of its functions, `"authentication."`

How does authentication work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication in Freeproxy is quite simple to set up.

There are two types of authentication as you can see. You can:

- Force the user to logon to the proxy service.
- Force the user to log on to the proxy service using windows
  authentication

For the first one:

1. Create users as required who will have access to the internet (on the window provided thus).
2. Create a group called Allowedusers, and add the users to the group.

For the second one it is not necessary to create users as the users will authenticate through their Windows login information. Thus logging in to the system means access to internet.

Comment: can u give more details how do i use this authentication

Answer (score 12):

The proxy authentication is done via additional HTTP request parameters named "Proxy-Authorization".

Upon first request to an proxy that requires authentication the proxy answers with an HTTP 407 that contains Proxy-Authenticate header. The client now knows that the proxy requires authentication and adds the Proxy-Authorization header containing the credentials. The proxy checks the request and removed this header before forwarding the request to the target server (if the authentication was successful).

The details can be found here:

- [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) section 3.6: Proxy-Authentication and Proxy-Authorization
- [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 14.34: Proxy-Authorization

Comment: does the order I put the Proxy-Authentication header in HTTP packet matter? I mean, can I add it right after HTTP method (CONNECT, POST, GET)?